# AngularJS Trigger Function within another Controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

1. Fetch/Trigger the message function `alertMessage();` within another controller.
2. Select specific message to be displayed using ID `alertMessage(id:2);`.

**Current Problems:**

2. Unable to Fetch or Trigger the message function `alertMessage();` from within the `statsCtrl` controller.
3. Apart from using the `var messageID = '1';` I am unable to specify the message ID through the alert function e.g `alertMessage(id:2);`

I'm still learning AngularJS, I know that I may need to develop a factory or a service but without knowing how this becomes tricky!
**Any help and advice would be helpful!**

**Controller One:**

```
fittingApp.controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$scope','$filter','$timeout','Notification','$sce','$mdDialog', function($scope,$filter,$timeout,Notification,$sce,$mdDialog) {
  // Dashboard > Username
  var username = 'Lucy'; // Test name
  $scope.username = username;

  // Dashboard > Alert Messages
  alertMessage();
  function alertMessage(){
    // Message ID
    var messageID = '1';
    // Messages
    var messages = {
      "results": [
        {'id':'1','icon':'','button':true,'title':'Welcome','subtitle':'Hi '+username+', welcome to the Virtual Fitting room','content': 'Here you will be able to browse through a selection of our dresses<br/>and shortlist them for future refrence. To help us find the best<br/>dress for you, please let us know a bit about yourself'},
        {'id':'2','icon':'','button':false,'title':'Raiding the Rails','subtitle':'','content': 'From the measurments you have supplied, we see you have a triangle body shape.<br/>Please wait while we get together the 5 best dresses for your shape.'},
        {'id':'3','icon':'','button':false,'title':'My Love List','subtitle':'','content': 'Any dresses you mark with a &#9829; will store<br/> into your Love list you can review at any<br/> point by clicking the heart icon.'},
        {'id':'4','icon':'','button':false,'title':'Show me the Style','subtitle':'','content': 'Feel free to look through the rest of our<br/> collection and &#9829; any that you like.'},
        {'id':'5','icon':'','button':false,'title':'Second Optionions','subtitle':'','content': 'It can be tough to choose, so why not ask<br/> the ones who know you best to help<br/>by voting for their favourites.'}
      ]
    };
    // Message Result
    var messageResult = $filter('filter')(messages.results,{id:messageID})[0];
    // Message HTML
    var message = '<h2>'+messageResult.title+'</h2><h3>'+messageResult.subtitle+'</h3><p>'+messageResult.content+'</p>';
    $scope.message = $sce.trustAsHtml(message);
    // Show Message
    $scope.showMessage = {
      active: true
    };
    // Hide Message
    $scope.hideMessage = function(){
      $scope.showMessage.active = !$scope.showMessage.active;
      // Trigger Notification
      notification();
    };
    // Hide 'Continue' Button
    $scope.hideButton = {
      active: true
    };
    if(messageResult.button === true){
      $scope.hideButton.active = !$scope.hideButton.active;
    }
  }

  // Dashboard > Notifications
  function notification(){
    // Bethan Test Notification
    $timeout(function(){
      Notification.bethan({
        message: 'Hi ' +username+ '! you’re not sure what to do? Hover the menu in the top right and click',
        positionY: 'bottom',
        positionX: 'left',
        delay: 10000,
        templateUrl: "views/notification.html"
      });
    }, 3000);
    // Rhiannon Test Notification
    $timeout(function(){
      Notification.rhiannon({
        message: 'This dress is perfect for a Triangle body shape like yours!',
        positionY: 'bottom',
        positionX: 'left',
        delay: null,
        templateUrl: "views/notification.html"
      });
    }, 6000);
  }
}]);
```

**Controller Two:**

```
fittingApp.controller('statsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  alertMessage();
}]);
```

**Full JS**

```
// START APP
var fittingApp = angular.module('fittingApp');

// Dashboard Controller
fittingApp.controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$scope','$filter','$timeout','Notification','$sce','$mdDialog','CustomService', function($scope,$filter,$timeout,Notification,$sce,$mdDialog,CustomService) {

    // Dashboard > Username
    var username = 'Lucy'; // Test name
    $scope.username = username;

    // Dashboard > Alert Messages
    alertMessage();
    function alertMessage(){
        // Message ID
        var messageID = '1';
        // Messages
        var messages = {
            "results": [
                {'id':'1','icon':'','button':true,'title':'Welcome','subtitle':'Hi '+username+', welcome to the Virtual Fitting room','content': 'Here you will be able to browse through a selection of our dresses<br/>and shortlist them for future refrence. To help us find the best<br/>dress for you, please let us know a bit about yourself'},
                {'id':'2','icon':'','button':false,'title':'Raiding the Rails','subtitle':'','content': 'From the measurments you have supplied, we see you have a triangle body shape.<br/>Please wait while we get together the 5 best dresses for your shape.'},
                {'id':'3','icon':'','button':false,'title':'My Love List','subtitle':'','content': 'Any dresses you mark with a &#9829; will store<br/> into your Love list you can review at any<br/> point by clicking the heart icon.'},
                {'id':'4','icon':'','button':false,'title':'Show me the Style','subtitle':'','content': 'Feel free to look through the rest of our<br/> collection and &#9829; any that you like.'},
                {'id':'5','icon':'','button':false,'title':'Second Optionions','subtitle':'','content': 'It can be tough to choose, so why not ask<br/> the ones who know you best to help<br/>by voting for their favourites.'}
            ]
        };
        // Message Result
        var messageResult = $filter('filter')(messages.results,{id:messageID})[0];
        // Message HTML
        var message = '<h2>'+messageResult.title+'</h2><h3>'+messageResult.subtitle+'</h3><p>'+messageResult.content+'</p>';
        $scope.message = $sce.trustAsHtml(message);
        // Show Message
        $scope.showMessage = {
        active: true
      };
        // Hide Message
        $scope.hideMessage = function(){
            $scope.showMessage.active = !$scope.showMessage.active;
            // Trigger Notification
            notification();
        };
        // Hide 'Continue' Button
        $scope.hideButton = {
            active: true
        };
        if(messageResult.button === true){
            $scope.hideButton.active = !$scope.hideButton.active;
        }
    }

    // Dashboard > Notifications
    function notification(){
        // Bethan Test Notification
        $timeout(function(){
            Notification.bethan({
                message: 'Hi ' +username+ '! you’re not sure what to do? Hover the menu in the top right and click',
                positionY: 'bottom',
                positionX: 'left',
                delay: 10000,
                templateUrl: "views/notification.html"
            });
        }, 3000);
        // Rhiannon Test Notification
        $timeout(function(){
            Notification.rhiannon({
                message: 'This dress is perfect for a Triangle body shape like yours!',
                positionY: 'bottom',
                positionX: 'left',
                delay: null,
                templateUrl: "views/notification.html"
            });
        }, 6000);
    }

    // Dashboard > Menu (FAB Speed Dial)
    menu();
    function menu(){
        $scope.hidden = false;
        // Menu Items
        $scope.items = [
            {name:"Help",icon:"svg/help.svg",direction:"left",backgroundColor:"rgb(239, 149, 73)"},
            {name:"Book",icon:"svg/book.svg",direction:"left",backgroundColor:"rgb(95, 205, 155)"},
            {name:"Contact",icon:"svg/contact.svg",direction:"left",backgroundColor:"rgb(32, 133, 188)"},
            {name:"Share",icon:"svg/share.svg",direction:"left",backgroundColor:"rgb(102, 181, 215)"},
            {name:"Exit",icon:"svg/exit.svg",direction:"left",backgroundColor:"rgb(255, 206, 97)"}
        ];
    }

    // Example
    $scope.$watchCollection(function() { return CustomService.showMsg; }, function(o, n){
        if(n === true){
            showMessage("Success");
        }
    });
    var showMessage = function(msg){
        alert(msg);
        CustomService.showMsg = false;
    };
    // END Example

}]);
// End Dashboard Controller

// Stats Controller
fittingApp.controller('statsCtrl', ['$scope', 'CustomService', function($scope, CustomService) {

    // Example
    $scope.clickMe = function(){
        console.log("Set true");
        CustomService.showMsg = true;
    };
    // END Example

    // Default Stats (Average UK Woman)
    defaultStats();
    function defaultStats(){
        $scope.height = 525; // 5'3"
        $scope.chest = 32; // 32"
        $scope.waist = 30; // 30"
        $scope.hips = 34; // 34"
        $scope.thighs = 20; // 20"
    }

    // Reset Stats
    $scope.resetStats = function(){
        defaultStats();
    };

    // Body Type Formula
    bodyShape();
    function bodyShape(){
        var bust = 32;
        var waist = 30;
        var hips = 34;
      var bustMeasure   = "";
        var waistMeasure  = "";
        var hipsMeasure   = "";
        var small   = "small";
        var medium  = "medium";
        var large   = "large";
        var shapeType = "";
        if ( bust <= 36 ) { bustMeasure = small;  }
        if ( bust <= 44 ) { bustMeasure = medium; }
        if ( bust >= 45 ) { bustMeasure = large;  }
        if ( waist <= 34 ) { waistMeasure = small;  }
        if ( waist <= 41 ) { waistMeasure = medium; }
        if ( waist >= 42 ) { waistMeasure = large;  }
        if ( hips <= 39 ) { hipsMeasure = small;  }
        if ( hips <= 47 ) { hipsMeasure = medium; }
        if ( hips >= 48 ) { hipsMeasure = large;  }
      var highestValue = Math.max(bust, waist, hips);
      var lowestValue = Math.min(bust, waist, hips);
      var difference = highestValue - lowestValue;
      if ( difference <= 5 ){
        shapeType = "Rectangle";
      }
      if (waist - bust > 5 && hips - bust > 5) {
          shapeType = "Triangle";
      }
      if (bust - waist > 5 && hips - waist > 5) {
          shapeType = "Hourglass";
      }
      if (waist - bust > 5 && waist - hips > 5) {
          shapeType = "Inverted Triangle";
      }
      if (hips - waist > 5 && hips - bust > 5) {
          shapeType = "Triangle";
      }
      if (bust - hips > (hips / 20)) {
          shapeType = "Inverted Triangle";
      }
      if ((bust - hips <= ( hips / 20)) && (waist > (bust * '.75'))) {
          shapeType = "Rectangle";
      }
      if (hips - bust > (bust/20)) {
         shapeType = "Triangle";
      }
      if ((waist <= (bust * '.75') && waist <= (hips * '.75'))) {
         shapeType = "Hourglass";
      }
        $scope.shapeType = shapeType;
    }
}]);
// End Stats Controller
// END APP
```

Comment: then end of my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725086/angular-unable-to-watch-ng-model-in-custom-directive/31728313#31728313) explains how to create a custom event aggregator which is what you need in this instance

Comment: @CallumLinington I don't have a clue where to start! Have you got any further advice, tips or a working example that I can dissect? Would a Plnkr help you with my issue?

Comment: yeah a plnker would help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to call functions of a controller from another controller using factory.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BSNjqlq5kdfIEaZ3ZlGB)

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function() { return CustomService; }, function(o, n){
    if(n.showMsg === true){
      showMessage("Success");
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried implementing the demo, I can see the 'Set True' console.log but the Alert is not triggering on click! I've updated by code above so you can see my entire JS, just incase I have something thats conflicting!

Comment: Are you sure the alert does't work. Because mine it works http://postimg.org/image/5srh7p4zx/

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood, I meant the Alert wasn't displaying on my version. i've re-updated my Git if you would like to review my code.

Comment: If that does not work try $broadcast https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Spent another couple hours looking into this and I still can't get this to work, Would you suggest I redeveloped the messaging function to work outside the controller somehow? I'm open to further suggestions and advice!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91080/discussion-between-shamal-perera-and-adamkwadsworth).